# how can I solve a equation like that $40939=200 \cdot 0.54 \cdot T+\sigma \cdot \varepsilon\cdot T^4$ with a simple scientific calculator?

Tags: numerical-methods

$\varepsilon = 0.8$ and 
$\sigma = 5.669 \cdot 10^{-8}$

We are only allowed to use simple scientific calculador during the tests. How can I solve this equation like that? Find T.

$40939=200 \cdot 0.54 \cdot T+\sigma \cdot \varepsilon\cdot T^4$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Newton's method

If you are allowed to use a calculator I'd recommend you use Newton's method:

1. Define the function

$$
f(T) = \sigma \epsilon T^4 + 200 \cdot 0.54 T - 40939
$$

2. Calculate the derivative

$$
f'(T) = 4\sigma \epsilon T^3 + 200 \cdot 0.54
$$

3. Define the recurrence

$$
T_{n + 1} = T_n - \frac{f(T_n)}{f'(T_n)} = T_n - \frac{\sigma \epsilon T_n^4 + 200 \cdot 0.54 T_n - 40939}{4\sigma \epsilon T_n^3 + 200 \cdot 0.54}
$$

4. Iterate away! I will start with $T_0 = 400$, from this you can calculate $T_1$, $\cdots$

$$
\begin{array}{ccc}\hline
n & T_n & f(T_n) \\ \hline
0 & 400 & 3 422.01 \\
1 & 371.39 & 33.9676 \\
2 & 371.10068848 & 0.0031 \\
3 & 371.10066165 & 2.18\times10^{-11} \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

After the fourth iteration you find the solution $T = 371.10066165$

> Even simpler

1. Isolate the linear term in your equation

$$
T = \frac{40939 - \sigma \epsilon T^4}{200 \cdot 0.54}
$$

2. Define the function

$$
g(T) = \frac{40939 - \sigma \epsilon T^4}{200 \cdot 0.54}
$$

3. Iterate the recursion

$$
T_{n + 1} = g(T_n)
$$

It converges slower, but at the end you get back the solution above

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you can compute a base value $T_0=40939/(200⋅0.54)=379.06481481...$ from the linear part of the equation. It remains to be seen if the 4th degree term constitutes a perturbation or has a substantial contribution to $T=T_0⋅x$.
$$
40939=200⋅0.54⋅T_0⋅x+σ⋅ε⋅T_0^4⋅x^4=40939x+936.3761480165862⋅x^4
$$
or reduced
$$
1=x+\delta⋅x^4,~~δ=0.02287247241057637.
$$
This indeed counts as perturbation, so that $x=1-δ+c_2δ^2+c_3δ^3+...$. Inserting this perturbation series gives
$$
0=δ⋅((1-δ+c_2δ^2+...)^4-1)+c_2δ^2+c_3δ^3+...,
$$
from where by comparing coefficients $c_2=4$ and $6+4c_2+c_3=0$,
$$
x\approx 1-δ+4δ^2-22δ^3=0.979\pm 0.002
$$
but the coefficients of this series grow fast, so that the error after $n$ terms is about $0.2^n$.

Or you could apply one or two iterations of Newton's method starting from $x_1=1-δ$,
$$
x_2=x_1-\frac{1+δ⋅x_1^3-x_1^{-1}}{3δ⋅x_1^2+x_1^{-2}}
=x_1\frac{2-x_1+2δ⋅x_1^4}{1+3δ⋅x_1^4}
$$
giving the iterates

```
0.978986870787873
0.9789899963061174
0.9789899963149125
```

or $T=371.10066165867$

Answer (score 0):

There are various approaches to numeric [root finding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm), all of which amount to guess and check.  They differ in how you choose the next guess based on what information you have gained so far.  For this equation I would first find which term on the right is important by solving the equation left after you ignore each one.  Often one is large and one is small, so
$$40939=200\cdot 0.54T\\T=\frac {40939}{200\cdot 0.54}\approx 379\\40939=0.8\cdot 5.669\cdot 10^{-8}T^4\\T=\left(\frac{40939}{0.8\cdot 5.669\cdot 10^{-8}}\right)^{1/4}\approx974$$
The first term is dominant because the second requires a much higher $T$.  Now write your equation in fixed point form
$$T=\frac 1{200\cdot 0.54}\left(40939-0.8\cdot 5.669\cdot 10^{-8}T^4\right)$$ start with $379$ and iterate to convergence.  Fixed point iteration often converges more slowly than Newton, but I find not needing to take the derivative is easier.